# HTML5 drag and drop child?

Tags: html

I have 2 containers which content can be dragged into.

Drag-able containers are declared like this;

```
<div id="boxL" class="bloqueL" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)">
```

Inside these containers Drag-able elements are declared like this;

```
<div id="'.$id_prefix.'_Block" class="'.$class.'"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
```

It is working but I have noticed that I can drag an element into another drag-able element which is not a container. It seams like, since they are inside a container that allow dropping they also allow dropping.

How should I prevent that. I dont want to drop a Block into another Block but only inside there container.